# Qt widget flickering on resize on a Mac machine

Tags: qt, qwidget, qt5.5

I am trying to move and resize a QWidget based on the mainWindow's position. Following is my code. This code works perfectly fine on Qt on a windows machine.

However, when I run the same qt project on a mac machine, the myWidget lags before moving to the MainWindow position. Also, myWidget flickers when I resize the MainWindow. I have tried to run the code in update block inside paint events and move events as well. They work correctly on a windows machine but I get the same flickering and lag on a Mac.

Could someone tell me why and any ways to correct this?

```html
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    panelWidth=this->width();
    myWidget->resize(panelWidth,panelHeight-50);
    myWidget->setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint));
    myWidget->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);

    QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(update()));
    timer->start(10);

}
void MainWindow::update()
{
    panelWidth=this->width();
    panelHeight=this->height();

   myWidget->move(this->pos().x(),this->pos().y()+30);
   myWidget->resize(panelWidth,panelHeight-50);
   
}
```

Comment: what happens if you disable the line setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground) ?

Comment: It still flickers. This attribute only sets the transparency. I can remove the flickering if I set the parent of mywidget to mainwindow but then I lose the transparency of the myWidget. I am facing a similar problem like this one: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-17548